# Given a Markov Chain, how can I find the probability from state $1$ to state $3$?

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

Suppose we have a transition matrix $3\times 3$, and the state space $S := \{1,2,3\}$:
\begin{align*}
P =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.2 & 0.4 & 0.2\\
0.3 & 0.6 & 0.1\\
0   & 0   & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

How can I find the probability from state $1$ to state $3$?

I think the probability is $0.2$, but $1$ can reach $2$ and then goes to $3$, I am confused about the steps.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks as if you are confused about the question:  $0.2$ in the top right is the single step probability, while in this case the probability of ever reaching state $3$ is $1$. Usually in a transition matrix each of the rows adds up to $1$ (or in another conventions the columns) but your third row does not; you could make state $3$ an absorbing state with a $1$ in the bottom right, in which case raising the transition matrix to a large power would make each of the elements of the third column close to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned by Henry, you first need to ensure that the probabilities in each row of the transition matrix add up to $1$, and I've done that by making state $3$ an absorbing one.

\begin{align*}
P =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.2 & 0.4 & 0.2\\
0.3 & 0.6 & 0.1\\
0   & 0   & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Let the steady state probabilities of being in state $1, 2$ and $3$ be $p,q,r$ respectively.
Then one more iteration won't change the probabilities, which means

$0.2p+0.3q+0*r=p$
$0.4p+0.6q +0*r=q$
$0.2p+0.1q+r=r$
$p+q+r = 1$

Solving the system of linear equations yields $p=0,q=0,r=1$